# How do I create a popup window when doing oauth?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, oauth, popup

I'm would like to do what lifestream and other sites have done with oauth authentication by using a pop up window.  They open a popup window which somehow wasn't blocked by the popup blocker and grey out their site.  Then upon allowing oauth access it says redirecting back to original site and kills the popup and returns the site to normal color.  How would I go about doing something like this?  If I posted anything I shouldn't have its alright because all these accounts are bogus anyway.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -10, accepted):

The thing is, this is not a pop-up window. It's what usually called lightbox. A js script like fancybox, lightbox and many others. You basically can open an iframe in a div with a absolut position and high z-index, then put an overlay underneath.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a popup.  Look at the red/yellow/green buttons and the url bar at the top.  You don't get those with lightbox/fancybox implementations.  Also, most OAuth implementations have IFrame busting javascript from what I understand -- so (AFAIK) it's not possible to use an IFrame approach with OAuth.

Answer (score 19):

In javascript, the [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) function will do this for you. With its api, you can set its location and get data from events occurring in it.

Popup blockers will not block this popup if it is created from a function that is executed when the user clicks a button. Popup blockers only block windows if there was no user input provided to create it.

Comment: Thanks for specifically pointing out that popup blockers dont block it because its on an action.