# Open Twitter Bootstrap Modal for Social Login with Django

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, python-social-auth

I just recently [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224434/open-new-window-for-social-login-and-then-close-and-return-to-parent-on-success) a very similar question to this but implemented this using javascript and had it open in a separate window altogether. I've come a lot further along since and began to implement twitter bootstrap and thought that using a modal would be perfect for implementing this same idea without opening more windows.

I've read up on similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153503/twitter-bootstrap-modal-external-urls-are-not-working/12153741#12153741) and found that it might be because of "origin policy restrictions."

What I have running is Django 1.6.1, Python-Social-Auth, & Twitter Bootstrap.
I have a link like so:

```
<a class="loginModalLink" 
    href="{% url 'social:begin' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}"
    data-target="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    Sign In
    </button>
</a>
```

And the corresponding modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">One fine body...
            </div>
        </div> <!-- ./modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- ./modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

I've also tried using the data-remote="" tag in the modal but without any luck.

Here's an error I get in my Javascript console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=r_basicprofile+r_em…mZhzisE8BHHksx6bOFDOnxDMKX4dS0&response_type=code&client_id=75l485e9k29snc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Has anyone ran into this problem before and figured out how to

Comment: You won't be able to load the contents using AJAX without the cross-origin authorisation, and even if you could it would be likely not to work because it would depend on local resources, such as CSS & images and a relative URL to post back to. And according to the comments on [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837993/how-do-i-create-a-popup-window-when-doing-oauth), most OAuth implementations don't support iFrames, so that's not an option for the modal dialog either. I think you're best off sticking with the pop-up window.

Comment: Although if you really wanted to pursue this line you could try calling the LinkedIn auth page on the server side, then (if necessary) inserting a BASE tag into the HTML to make it appear as though the page comes from LinkedIn, and then serving it up on the client. But whilst this might work for the initial page I don't think it'll work when you post back from the authentication page.